# Where a binary inside a JavaScript module should live?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, jq

I'm the creator of [node-jq](https://github.com/sanack/node-jq). That's just a wrapper around [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and the ability to call to jq functionality inside node.

The idea of `node-jq` is to download and build on install-time the binary of jq and move it to its own folder: `node_modules/node-jq/bin/jq`

Many users of the library expect the binary to be publicly available. Like calling `npx jq` and being able to run jq straight. I added the property to the `package.json` called `"bin"` and points to `node_modules/node-jq/bin/jq` but that fails since npm tried to change the permissions before installing and that caused to break the package.

I tried very hard to read where on the npm documentation they explain where it should live and how I can accomplish having both behaviours, the possibility to expose with the keyword bin from packagejson the jq binary and installing jq on install time.

Here are some links for reference about the issues that I mention:

- https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/issues/161
- https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/issues/167
- https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/issues/171

Comment: What do you mean `but that fails since npm tried to change the permissions before installing and that caused to break the package.`.

Comment: When I set the bin property pointing to `node_modules/node-jq/bin/jq`. NPM was failing, since it would try to change permisions (on install time) to a binary that doesn't exist yet.